# how to pass string message from servlet and catch it in HTML file using json?

Tags: html, json, servlets

I have a primitive problem, I'm trying to send a string message in the servlet inside `doGet` function, then catch this message in the HTML function using JSON? Any help?

Comment: String messege="on";
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            gson.toJson(messege);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            PrintWriter out1 = response.getWriter();
            out1.print( gson.toJson(messege));  
            out1.flush();

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var request = ({"message":'Hello from browser'});
    var jsonobj=JSON.stringify(request);
    $.ajax({
        data: {para:jsonobj},
        dataType: 'json',
        url: './signInServlet',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(jsonObj){
            alert(jsonObj.message);     
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Ajax readyState: '+xhr.readyState+'\nstatus: '+xhr.status + ' ' + err);
        }
    });
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

First, if you insert ur code in doGet, you need in ajax to do a GET request.

You need to give an url to your servlet in the web inf file.

Then you need a javascript file (linked in your html). This js file would have smt like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "urlInWebInf", function( data ) {
       console.log(data);
    });
)}
```

It should display your json in the console.

Hope it helps!